# Script to replace/delete characters in direcory and file names (work in progress)

Tags: bash, replace, rename, filenames

I am trying to delete a set of characters like single quote (') and spaces from file names and directories. Example, I have:
Directory `I'm confused` which contains file `you're right`

So far, I have been able to create a short script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *; do mv "$f" `echo $f | tr ' ' '_'`; done
for f in *; do mv "$f" `echo $f | tr -d \'`; done
```

which renames the dir to `Im_confused` as intended. The file in the directory of course is not affected.

How can I replace and delete characters in subdirectories as well?

Comment: And where exactly are you stuck? 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: I have to start at 1. I only started with that short script, then investigating/reading how to define depths of directories, but found no solution.

Comment: This is not clear from your question. I suggest that you edit your question, so that it is clear what you are askig (the recursive traversal is unrelated to what you actually do to the entries you found) Did you consider using the `find` command for doing the recursion?

Comment: I took the liberty to replace your _bash_ tag by a _shell_ tag, because your question relates to POSIX shell, not bash.

Comment: My first thought was to keep it more universal by using posix shell and the directions I was taken to suggested this syntax. Of course I am open to suggestions that point other ways.

Answer (score 1):

For example, for depth 2, the command is:

```
REP_CHARS=" →" # Characters to replace
DEL_CHARS="'," # Characters to delete
find . -maxdepth 2 | sort -r |
  sed -n -e '/^\.\+$/!{p;s#.\+/#&\n#;p}' |
  sed "n;n;s/[$DEL_CHARS]//g;s/[$REP_CHARS]/_/g" |
  sed "n;N;s/\n//" |
  xargs -L 2 -d '\n' mv 2>/dev/null
```

1. Use `find` with `-maxdepth`.
2. Use `sort` to order from the deepest.
3. Use `sed` to replace only the end part.
4. Use `xargs` to perform mv.

```
[Original]

├── I'm confused
│   ├── I'm confused
│   │   └── you're right
│   ├── comma, comma
│   └── you're right
└── talking heads-love → building on fire
    └── talking heads-love → building on fire

[After]

├── Im_confused
│   ├── Im_confused
│   │   └── you're right
│   ├── comma_comma
│   └── youre_right
└── talking_heads-love___building_on_fire
    └── talking_heads-love___building_on_fire
```

Comment: as of now I'm trying to clean up some mp3 albums. I don't want to have all of these characters in the directory and filenames: comma, single quote, space. I found even "talking heads-love → building on fire", see that arrow...

Comment: while the second suggested script works for replacing and deleting exactly 1 character, I wonder how to have a list of characters processed? Do I need to add an array and how do I do this?

Comment: You can specify multiple characters using strings in the above example. I rewrote my answer as to replace " " and "→", to delete "'" and ",". Be careful when specifying characters that are regarded as special characters in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this rename script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for f in *; do
    g=$(printf '%s' "$f" | tr -s '[:space:]' _ | tr -d "'")
    [ "$f" != "$g" ] && mv -v "$f" "$g"
done
```

and this `find` invocation

```sh
find . -depth -execdir /absolute/path/to/rename.sh '{}' +
```

- -depth does a depth-first descent into the file hierarchy so the files are renamed before their parent directories
- -execdir performs the command in the directory where the file is found, so the value of `$f` only contains the filename not its directory as well.

Demo

```
$ mkdir -p "a b/c d/e f"
$ touch a\ b/c\ d/e\ f/"I'm confused"
$ touch "a file with spaces"
$ tree
.
├── a\ b
│   └── c\ d
│       └── e\ f
│           └── I'm\ confused
├── a\ file\ with\ spaces
└── rename.sh

3 directories, 3 files

$ find . -depth -execdir /tmp/rename.sh '{}' +
renamed 'a b' -> 'a_b'
renamed 'a file with spaces' -> 'a_file_with_spaces'
renamed "I'm confused" -> 'Im_confused'
renamed 'e f' -> 'e_f'
renamed 'c d' -> 'c_d'

$ tree
.
├── a_b
│   └── c_d
│       └── e_f
│           └── Im_confused
├── a_file_with_spaces
└── rename.sh

3 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it works. Thank you very much!    I will now expand this script to my needs, means: I need to replace comma ";" and other characters in file names...